# python flatten an array of array

Tags: python, arrays, data-manipulation, flatten

I have an array of array, something like that:

```
array([[array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668],
      dtype=int64)],
       [array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665],
      dtype=int64)],
       [array([46842, 26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285,
       17616, 25146, 32645, 41276], dtype=int64)],
       ...,
       [array([24534,  8230, 14267,  9352,  3543, 29397,   900, 32398, 34262,
       37646, 11930, 37173], dtype=int64)],
       [array([25157], dtype=int64)],
       [array([ 8859, 20850, 19322,  8075], dtype=int64)]], dtype=object)
```

what I want is

```
     array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668,33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665,46842, 26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285,17616, 25146, 32645, 41276
               ...,
24534,  8230, 14267,  9352,  3543, 29397,   900, 32398, 34262,
               37646, 11930, 37173,25157 8859, 20850, 19322,  8075, dtype=object)
```

I have searched some solution for that, but seems that all of them are for np.array or list, which are not work for array.

```
    functools.reduce(operator.iconcat, orders2.values.tolist(), [])
[array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668],
       dtype=int64),
 array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665],
       dtype=int64),
 array([46842, 26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285,
        17616, 25146, 32645, 41276], dtype=int64),...
    orders2.values.flatten()
array([array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668],
      dtype=int64),
       array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665],
      dtype=int64),
```

I couldnt even convert the array to list

```
[sub.tolist() for sub in orders2.values]
    [array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668],
           dtype=int64),
     array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665],
           dtype=int64),
     array([46842, 26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285,
            17616, 25146, 32645, 41276], dtype=int64),...
        orders2.values.flatten()
    array([array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668],
          dtype=int64),
           array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665],
          dtype=int64),...
```

I find it is hard to get some information about array class ,everything is list or np.array

Comment: What do you mean by `array` here?  It sure looks like you have a `numpy` array of arrays.  If so, why isn't there a `[numpy]` tag?  There is a builtin `array` module but I don't think supports this kind of structure.

Comment: Another way to put the question, what module `imports` did you do?

Comment: Can you improve this question by giving important information like which libraries you're using as well as trimming down the irrelevant data to the minimal data needed to convey your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension, then convert back to `array`:

```
>>> arr = array([[array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668],
      dtype='int64')],
       [array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665],
      dtype='int64')],
       [array([46842, 26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285,
       17616, 25146, 32645, 41276], dtype='int64')],
       [array([24534,  8230, 14267,  9352,  3543, 29397,   900, 32398, 34262,
       37646, 11930, 37173], dtype='int64')],
       [array([25157], dtype='int64')],
       [array([ 8859, 20850, 19322,  8075], dtype='int64')]], dtype=object)
>>> array([x for i in arr.tolist() for x in i[0].tolist()])
array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668,
       33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665, 46842,
       26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285, 17616,
       25146, 32645, 41276, 24534,  8230, 14267,  9352,  3543, 29397,
         900, 32398, 34262, 37646, 11930, 37173, 25157,  8859, 20850,
       19322,  8075])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [141]: array=np.array; 
     ...: arr = array([[array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668], 
     ...:       dtype='int64')], 
     ...:        [array([33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665], 
     ...:       dtype='int64')], 
     ...:        [array([46842, 26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285, 
     ...:        17616, 25146, 32645, 41276], dtype='int64')], 
     ...:        [array([24534,  8230, 14267,  9352,  3543, 29397,   900, 32398, 34262, 
     ...:        37646, 11930, 37173], dtype='int64')], 
     ...:        [array([25157], dtype='int64')], 
     ...:        [array([ 8859, 20850, 19322,  8075], dtype='int64')]], dtype=object)                           
In [142]: np.concatenate(arr.ravel())                                                                           
Out[142]: 
array([33120, 28985,  9327, 45918, 30035, 17794, 40141,  1819, 43668,
       33754, 24838, 17704, 21903, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665, 46842,
       26434, 39758, 27761, 10054, 21351, 22598, 34862, 40285, 17616,
       25146, 32645, 41276, 24534,  8230, 14267,  9352,  3543, 29397,
         900, 32398, 34262, 37646, 11930, 37173, 25157,  8859, 20850,
       19322,  8075])
```

The shape is 2d:

```
In [143]: arr.shape                                                                                             
Out[143]: (6, 1)
```

`arr.ravel()` makes it 1d (6,),  `np.concatenate` joins a list (or iterable) of arrays.